# What are the pros and cons of only importing the components needed "from X import Y" when the documented use is importing the whole package?

Tags: python, python-import

The only component I need from [pycountry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry) is 'Languages'. I like to avoid importing anything more than needed, so I am tempted to do:

```
from pycountry import Languages
```

However, the only documented use I can find is:

```
import pycountry
```

Without knowing more, the only prudent option seems to be the documented route. As a module user, what else should I be aware of or consider?

FYI: I looked at [In python, what are the pros and cons of importing a class vs. importing the class's module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937233), which had some good information but was focused on devs creating a module rather than using a module.

Update: I looked at [Is `import module` better coding style than `from module import function`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258). This has a wealth of good information, but I didn't see my fundamental misunderstanding addressed. I had assumed that `from X import Y` only imported what I asked for, but it imports the whole module.

Update2:
[PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring)'s comment that "*FWIW, all forms of import actually import the entire module*" caught me by surprise. Since I got a `NameError: name 'pycountry' is not defined` on everything else in pycountry, I assumed nothing else was imported. Checking around (for example ['import module' vs. 'from module import function'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403)) I can see that 2ring is right and my assumptions were false.

Re: [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s comment about being able to recognize the source when looking at my code. Since the first thing I would want to do is create my own alias `langs = pycountry.languages`, I eliminate any advantage either import form had.

Combining the comments from 2Ring and chepner, there is no advantage to the `from pycountry import Languages` form in my case and I shall use `import pycountry`.

At this point I feel like my question has been fully answered.

Comment: FWIW, all forms of `import` actually import the entire module - they have to, otherwise the stuff in it wouldn't work properly. The only way they differ is in which _names_ become available in your namespace.

Comment: I'd argue it depends on whether you (or your readers) are going to recognize a particular name as being imported from a particular module. This is somewhat subjective. For example, I'd recognized something like `itemgetter` as coming from `operator`; likewise, I don't really need to know which module `mul` or `add` are from (`operator` again) to have a good idea what they do...

Comment: ...  On the other hand, I might be hard pressed to identify where `tmp_file` comes from. (`os`? no, that's `tmpfile`. `tempfile`? Plausible, but that module doesn't define anything by that name. Must be defined in the current module, or from some other module.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is \`import module\` better coding style than \`from module import function\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258/is-import-module-better-coding-style-than-from-module-import-function)

Answer (score 1):

Summary:
I had a fundamental misunderstanding of import. I thought that:

```
from pycountry import Languages                 #FMIC
```

only imported the component I asked for, but it actually imports the whole `pycountry` module. The only difference between the FMIC form and the 'import module' form is that the FMIC form puts the requested *component* into my namespace (in my case `Languages`) and `import pycountry` puts the *module* (pycountry) into my namespace. In either case, a single object is added to my namespace.

Since the first thing I do is create an alias (either `langs = Language('<path>/iso639-3.json')` or `langs = pycountry.languages`), I now have 2 objects in my namespace: 'langs' and the imported object. Regardless of the form used to import, my usage will be no different (ex: `current_lang = langs.get(alpha_2='en')`.

See [Is import module better coding style than from module import function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258) for a discussion of many different cases and the advantages of the 'import module' form.