# Wierd attribute error with importing into directories

Tags: python, python-import

I have a directory tree as follows:

```
main.py
dir1
  sub1.py
  sub2.py
```

In `main.py`:

```py
import dir1.sub1
```

In `dir1/sub1.py`:

```py
def f1() -> None:
    print("f1")


import dir1.sub2

dir1.sub2.f2()
```

In `dir1/sub2.py`:

```py
import dir1.sub1


def f2() -> None:
    dir1.sub1.f1()
    print("f2")
```

When I run `main.py`, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dir1.sub1
  File "...\dir1\sub1.py", line 7, in <module>
    dir1.sub2.f2()
  File "...\dir1\sub2.py", line 5, in f2
    dir1.sub1.f1()
AttributeError: module 'dir1' has no attribute 'sub1'. Did you mean: 'sub2'?
```

(Where the `...` at the beginning of the file path is my working directory.)

If I change `main.py` to

```py
import dir1.sub2
```

I get a slightly different error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dir1.sub2
  File "...\dir1\sub2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dir1.sub1
  File "...\dir1\sub1.py", line 7, in <module>
    dir1.sub2.f2()
AttributeError: module 'dir1' has no attribute 'sub2'
```

If I move `sub1.py` and `sub2.py` to the same directory as `main.py` and re‐direct imports as necessary, I get the expected output of

```
f1
f2
```

Why does this happen, and how can I make it not happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use absolute import because Python 3 only supports that. In Python 2 your method will work. So for example if you have `import dir1.sub2` change it to `from dir1 import sub2`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16004535/17139260).

Note: I've tested it with your setup and it works.