# How to understand from . import in python?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to python and flask framework.

for below codes:

```
from flask import Blueprint
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
from . import views, errors
```

I found python has many import ways, for example:

```
import foo
import foo.bar
from foo import bar
from foo import bar, baz
from foo import *
from foo import bar as fizz
```

but how to understand `from . import ...`?

Comment: You could start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks a lot! I think I am moving too quickly, I should start from beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `import XXX`, you import all the contents of XXX under the namespace XXX, and you have access to them using XXX.abc, XXX.example etc...

When you use `from XXX import abc`, you only overwrite the variable abc of your `globals()` dictionnary. The special `from XXX import *` does the same, but for all variables whose name doesn't begins with an underscore.

Finally, the "as" keyword allows you to give to the imported module/function/variable the name you want.

When you have a module containing some folders, and you want to import from another file, . refers to the directory containing the current file, .. to the directory containing it, and so on.

For a less concise / more precise answer : [`from ... import` vs `import .`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import)

Answer (score 2):

```
from . import foo, bar
```

It means import foo, bar from current directory.

```
from foo import *
```

means from module foo import all items. But I think this is not a good practice.If you can and need only few items from a module do it like normal import rather than this one. For more info check [here.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)