# NameError: global name 'fileinput' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, global

**(Before you click "Duplicate", none of the solutions on ANY of the others work)**

I am working in Python 2.7.11, trying to convert my code from Python 3.5. I managed to remove all the syntax errors, apart from this annoying one.

> NameError: global name 'fileinput' is not defined

**Here is my code (The ENTIRETY):**

```
from fileinput import *
from sys import *

callingstops=[]

def Main_Menu ():
    print'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    print'RAILWAY SCHEDULE AND DISPATCHING SYSTEM V1.1 - PROVIDED BY ROBSKI'
    print'\n'
    print'Please choose one of the options:'
    print'1) Check Schedule'
    print'2) Add schedule'
    print'3) Enter Delays Report'
    print'4) Delete Schedule'
    print''
    print'0) EXIT'
    Option = int(raw_input("==> "))
    if Option == 1:
        checkschedule()
    if Option == 2:
        addschedule()
    if Option == 3:
        delays()
    if Option == 4:
        delete()
    else:
        sys.exit



def checkschedule ():
    file = open("Schedule.txt", "r")
    Scheduledetails = file.read()
    file.close()
    print'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    print(Scheduledetails)
    Main_Menu()

def addschedule ():
    user1 = raw_input('Enter time in xxxx format: ')
    dest = raw_input('Enter Destination of train: ')
    op = raw_input('Enter NR Operator Abbreviaton: ')
    long = raw_input('Enter number of carriages: ')
    notes = raw_input('Remarks (Running days etc.): ')
    callingno = int(raw_input('How much calling points are there? (NOT CHANGEABLE): '))
    for i in range(0,callingno):
        callingstops=[]
        callingstops.append(raw_input('Enter the name of stop '+str(i+1)+' (If your stop is a request, put "(r)" at the end): '))
    file = open("Schedule.txt", "a")
    file.write ("\n\n | Time: "+user1+"\n | Destination: "+dest+"\n | Operator Abbreviation: "+op+"\n | No. of carriages: "+long+"\n | Remarks: "+notes)
    for item in callingstops:
        file.write("\n | Calling at: "+item)
    file.close()
    Main_Menu()

def delays ():
    delaytitle = raw_input("Enter title of delay (Will be saved in seperate doc, overrides any other file with same name): ")
    delaydesc = raw_input("Enter description of delay in detail: ")
    file = open(delaytitle+".txt", "w")
    file.write("Delay report:\n"+delaydesc)
    file.close()

def delete ():
    train = raw_input("Enter the train time that you want to remove (You MUST have the file closed): ")
    train = train.strip()
    train_found_on = None # Rememberes which line the train time is located

    for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.fileinput('Schedule.txt', inplace=1)): # Open the file for in-place writing
        if 'Time:' in line and train in line: # Don't transfer the lines which match input
            train_found_on = i
            continue
        if train_found_on and i < (train_found_on + 7): # Neither the lines after that
            continue
        sys.stdout.write(line) # But write the others
        Main_Menu()

Main_Menu()
```

(In case you are wondering, I am converting to be able to use py2exe. I failed with PyInstaller)

Comment: Did you try `import fileinput` instead of `from fileinput import *` (which is discouraged anyway)? And then it should be `fileinput.FileInput('Schedule.txt', inplace=1)`

Comment: Just do `fileinput("Schedule.txt", inplace=1)` instead of `fileinput.fileinput(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the statement

```
from <modulename> import <names>
```

It doesn't bind the module name, it just binds the individual names that you imported as local names. So you should just call `fileinput()`, not `fileinput.fileinput()`.

If you want to bind the module name, you should use

```
import fileinput
```

See [`from ... import` vs `import .`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import)

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: FIXED. I used a comment above, and it worked after a try that I did earlier.

Comment: You'll get that error if you do `import fileinput` and then try to call `fileinput()` instead of `fileinput.fileinput()`. Do you understand the difference between binding the module name and function name?