# Does python do something extra with a multi-segment import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I saw the following in a student's script, and to my surprise it works:

```
>>> import os.path
```

The question, in brief, is: How is this **different** from simple `import os`? Or is it the same, except for necessitating that `os.path` exists?

As you can see below, it doesn't define `path` in my scope but `os`.

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'os']
```

So the question is: What does python do with this? For sure, it imports (and hence executes) the module `os`. It also ensures that `os.path` does resolve to something valid. (Thanks to @Lee and @Stuart for the links to the documentation that confirms it.) But is there more? Or is `import pkg.submod` always equivalent to `import pkg` (provided `pkg.submod` exists)?

If I import `os`, it already imports/executes any modules that `os` itself imports; so `os.path` is already loaded. Are there arrangements (not too exotic) where importing `pkg.submod` could lead to different code being executed, or in different order, or otherwise having different side effects, than just importing `pkg`? And are there legitimate use cases for the multi-segment form? (To put it differently: What's the point?)

Comment: the relevant docs are here https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Note that `os.path` is a special case, since there is no actual submodule by that name; `os` itself imports `posixpath` or `ntpath` as `path` as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching):

> [The fully qualified name of the module] will be used in various phases of the import search, and it
>   may be the dotted path to a submodule, e.g. `foo.bar.baz`. In this case,
>   Python first tries to import `foo`, then `foo.bar`, and finally
>   `foo.bar.baz`. If any of the intermediate imports fail, an `ImportError`
>   is raised.

So, to answer your original question, it seems that if `os` is a valid package, then the **whole** module is imported. So, as you suggest, the sub-module form would be used to validate that `os.path` exists within the `os` module, rather than just importing the module `os.path`.

If you want to **only** import the `path` module, then you can use the `from ... import ...` syntax:

```
>>> from os import path
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'path']
```

See also: [`from … import` vs `import .`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21547572/341459)

Comment: The whole module is imported for sure, sorry I didn't make it clear that I knew that. The question is what other effects there are. Are there differences? If I just import `os`, doesn't it already import everything `os` imports, hence also `path`?

Comment: Yes, I guess that `import os.path` can be used to validate that `path` exists within the `os` module, otherwise it would raise an `ImportError`.