# Creating datetime objects in UTC without timezone that can be imported by Matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, timezone, pytz

I have a list of `datetime` objects which are created this way:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

_year = 2018
_month = 2
_day = 3
_hour = 14
_minute = 30
csv_timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')

csv_dt = datetime(_year, _month, _day, _hour, _minute)
print('csv_dt')
print(csv_dt)
```

Which later I want to consume in UTC for Matplotlib:

```
utc_dt = csv_timezone.localize(csv_dt).astimezone(pytz.utc)
print('utc_dt')
print(utc_dt)
```

The result is as follows:

```
csv_dt
2018-02-03 14:30:00
utc_dt
2018-02-03 13:30:00+00:00
```

As stated before, I want to use those objects in Matplotlib. Which, as per documentation, expects the following datetime object:

> Date formatting
>   Commonly, in Python programs, dates are represented as datetime objects, so we have to first convert other data values into datetime objects, sometimes by using the dateutil companion module, for example:
>
> import datetime
>
> date = datetime.datetime(2009, 03, 28, 11, 34, 59, 12345)
>
> or
>
> import dateutil.parser
>
> datestrings = ['2008-07-18 14:36:53.494013','2008-07-2014:37:01.508990', '2008-07-28 14:49:26.183256']
>
> dates = [dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in datestrings]
>
> Once we have the datetime objects, in order to let Matplotlib use them, we have to convert them into floating point numbers that represent the number of days since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> To do that, Matplotlib itself provides several helper functions contained in the matplotlib.dates module:
>
> • date2num(): This function converts one or a sequence of datetime objects to float values representing days since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (the fractional parts represent hours, minutes, and seconds)
>
> (Excerpt from Matplotlib for Python Developers, Sandro Tosi, Ed. PACKT PUBLISHING 2009. Page 95)

So I do not understand why the `datetime` object `date2num` function is expecting has the following form:

```
2008-07-20 14:37:01.508990
```

While the one I am generating has this form:

```
2018-02-03 13:30:00+00:00
```

The error I am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7d0a84cb48da> in <module>
     20 
     21 # Convert to matplotlib required
---> 22 mpl_times =  mpl.dates.date2num(times)
     23 
     24 plt.figure()
```

`times` is:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
times
['2018-01-12 07:00:00+01:00', '2018-01-12 07:01:00+01:00', '2018-01-12 07:02:00+01:00' ..... ]
```

**How could I convert from my format to the format expected by `date2num`?**

Comment: You do not show the error you are getting (only the start of the traceback). Also it is not shown how you create `times`. Datetime objects do not have any format. You use the *string* you get from some unknown operation and try to use it as datetime object. Instead you need to use the datetime object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you import matplotlib.dates?
Can you try

```
    from matplotlib import dates as dt
    ....
    ....
    mpl_times =  dt.date2num(times)
```

The following code works for me

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz
    from matplotlib import dates as dt

    _year = 2018
    _month = 2
    _day = 3
    _hour = 14
    _minute = 30
    csv_timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')

    csv_dt = datetime(_year, _month, _day, _hour, _minute)
    print('csv_dt')
    print(csv_dt)

    utc_dt = csv_timezone.localize(csv_dt).astimezone(pytz.utc)
    print('utc_dt')
    print(utc_dt)
    print (dt.date2num(utc_dt))
```

The output is `736728.5625`

Comment: `import matplotlib as mpl` so it is the same package

Comment: Did you try `from matplotlib import dates as dt`?
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import)

Comment: It is working for me. Didn't worked while imported as `import matplotlib as mpl`. Got the `AttributeError`. Don't know, why it is not working for you.