# Why use "from <module> import <something>" after "import <module>"?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to understand why in some code it is common practice to **import a module first and afterwards importing specific member from the module**.

```py
import module_a
from module_a import member_a
```

Is it just out of pure **laziness** to not have to write `module_a.member_a` and instead access `member_a` directly?

Here's the **code snippet** my question originates from:

```py
import spinup
from spinup.utils.run_utils import ExperimentGrid
from spinup.utils.serialization_utils import convert_json
```

Comment: It have no sense, just for lazy access

Comment: "Is it just out of pure laziness to not have to write module_a.member_a and instead access member_a directly?" >  yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`from ... import\` vs \`import .\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it just out of pure laziness to not have to write `module_a.member_a` and instead access `member_a` directly?

Yes essentially, It allows one to use any functions or classes in `spinup`, with `spinup.foo` and `spinup.Bar`.  It's subjectively preferable to use the `spinup.foo` way for most of the time, since this way it's really clear from where the function you're using is defined.

This technique also enables the use of `ExperimentGrid` without specifying `spinup.utils.run_utils.ExperimentGrid` every time it's used.
This is especially useful with classes/types when using [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
def foo(param: ExperimentGrid) -> ExperimentGrid:
```

is a lot cleaner than

```
def foo(param: spinup.utils.run_utils.ExperimentGrid) -> spinup.utils.run_utils.ExperimentGrid:
```