# How to mimic the use of "import module" when I have to use "from module import method"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

[Google OAuth2 implementation in Python](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is packaged in such a way that I have to

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials...
```

Since I prefer to be explicit with the place my external methods come from, I would prefer very much to

```
import google.oauth2

credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials...
```

but this does not work, [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57772799/903011) neatly explains why (there are also many [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303305/903011) [good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57160002/903011) explantions, more or less ion-depth).

**Is there a way to mimic the "full path notation" so that I can use the second version, with the restrictions forcing me to use `from module import ...`?**

I tried

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account as google.oauth2.service_account

credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials....
```

but I get

```
  File "d:\Nextcloud\dev-perso\testing\googlecalendar\googlecalendar.py", line 4
    from google.oauth2 import service_account as google.oauth2.service_account
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there another solution, or am I stuck with the short names?

Note: I could

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account as google_oauth2_service_account

credentials = google_oauth2_service_account.Credentials...
```

but this is not that elegant (which is a subjective opinion, and which I will end up using if there are no better solutions)

Comment: You must be a Java programmer ;-)  Use the short names, and make your modules short, that way there is no confusion as to where names are coming from - in addition you don't need to type so much, other programmers don't need to read so much, and you're following the standard Python way of doing things (it's a win-win-win!)

Comment: You do realise that if you want to use ˋgoogle.oauth2.service_accountˋ, you must ˋimport google.oauth2.service_accountˋ, not just ˋimport google.oauth2ˋ?

Comment: @thebjorn ˋgoogleˋ is an external package, it’s not up to the OP to change its layout.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm saying to just use `from google.oauth2 import service_account` as every other Python programmer expects you to do (including the people who wrote the docs for this package).

Comment: @thebjorn: no I am just an amateur/home Python developer for 10 years or so. I find that using `frac` instead of `math.extended.rationsl.frac` makes reading code way more difficult. But as I mentioned this is subjective and not related to the question. I am glad you know all Python programmer in the world, since "every other one" would use the short form.

Comment: You should stop at the module level (not the function level), ie. `from math.extended import rationsl` then use `rationsl.frac(...)`. This should give enough context in any well-designed package.

Comment: ps: of course I know every other Python programmer - at least for a suitable definition of "every" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just import the module `service_account` by using absolute path:

```
import google.oauth2.service_account
google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials
#<class 'google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials'>
```