# NameError when trying to use the SIGHUP signal

Tags: python, python-import

I wanted to catch a `SIGHUP` signal in my Python program. But I ran into the problem that Python doesn't recognize the signal name:

```
import signal
import time

def handler(sig, frame):
  print("SIGNAL:", sig)


signal (SIGHUP, handler)

while True:
  time.sleep(1)
```

Python does not recognize `SIGHUP` and gives an error. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Given this import statement you would have to use `signal.SIGHUP`, not `SIGHUP`, and `signal.signal`, not `signal`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python you have to explicitly import the signals themselves. This should work:

```
from signal import signal, SIGHUP
import time 

def handler(sig, frame):
  print("SIGNAL:", sig) 

signal (SIGHUP, handler) 

while True: 
  time.sleep(1)
```