# What's the use of '.' in python import statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

What is the difference between `from math import floor` and `import math.floor` ?

`from math import floor`  - works perfectly.

`import math.floor` - does not work.

I'm assuming that `.` is used for referencing files and `floor` isn't a file, its just a class in `math`?

Comment: Math is a package and floor is a module within that.. The dot notation helps you to load only certain modules within the package rather than the whole module.. The module again here can be a file or a set of files.

Comment: `math.floor` is not a module – it is a *function*. While `import x.y` imports a submodule from a module, this is not the case here. That is why OP indicates an error. If it were a proper submodule, it would load properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help explain this we'll be using the dir() function: with specific examples. And how you can check these for yourself.

**What's the use of '**.**' in import statements?**   
'**.**' quite literally sets the parent directory of import search.  
This is reserved for packages, and is related to use of the `'__path__ '` attribute.

You can check this yourself like so. Lets go ahead and import numpy and math:

```
import numpy, math
print(dir(numpy))
```

and look for the **`'__path__'`** attribute to determine if something is a package or not:  Finding **`'__path__'`** you know numpy is a package.

**Why it does not work when trying `import math.floor`?**

First, we need to understand what and how `import "whatever"` is searching.  
For simplicity you can think of:  
**import whatever = look for "whatever", if found: look in "whatever" for `'__name__'` , if `'__name__'` not in "whatever" raise Error ModuleNotFound**

Let's look at `import math`:
python will search for math, and once found, will search in math for its **`'__name__'`** attribute, because this is what import uses to resolve its pointer assignment (this is relevant, but not to this explanation).

You can use:

```
print(dir(math))
```

and look for **`'__name__'`** attribute to check whether something is a module or not: Finding **`'__name__'`** attribute, you know math is a module.

and if you were to try

```
print(dir(math.floor))
```

you will not find **`'__name__'`** because floor is not a module and cannot be "found" by python `import math.floor` **or** `import floor`.

Therefore when you try `import math.floor` (assigning math as the parent directory is irrelevant). 
python will look for math; finding math, python will search in math for floor; finding floor, python will search for floor's **`'__name__ '`** attribute; and unable to find the **`'__name__'`** attribute it  will raise an error ModuleNotFound.

Using `from` alters the search pattern so that it becomes look for (module, attribute - **`'__specific__'`**) instead of (module, attribute - **`' __name__'`**)   
in the case of `from math import floor` this means python will search for **math's** **`'__floor__'`** attribute' instead of **math's** **`'__name__'`**  attribute. It will find the floor attribute in math and work fine.

Comment: Actually your verbose answer made it clearer to me.

Answer (score 5):

from math import floor lets you use only "floor" in your code, but import math.floor means you have to use "math.floor" whenever you want to use that.

[`from ... import` vs `import .`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import)

Edit: To answer your question more thoroughly, the reason why math.floor doesn't work is because as earlier comments stated it's a function, not a submodule. In fact, math doesn't have any submodules, so even math.* gives the same error.

Comment: As OP mentions, `import math.floor` generates a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Maybe you're thinking of `import math`?

Comment: You're totally right, I checked in PyCharm and on hover it gives me the same error.