# How do I assign the types for python-modules?

Tags: python, pygame, typing

Here is an example with pygame (Types do not get inferred):

```
import pygame

pygame.display.set_mode((size))
```

Types do get inferred:

```
from pygame import display

display.set_mode((size))
```

Well, this library throws an error when importing single modules and using pygame.init(). Is there another way to use the first example and type the modules afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from pygame import *` is the best thing to use in this situation.

In your situation, `init()` can be simply used along with `display.set_mode((size))` and any other objects within the pygame module.

This is due to the fact that `import *` imports the module and makes reference to all the public objects defined by the module ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21547572/15675913)).