# Why can't I use projectname.file to import

Tags: python, django

I add a custom_site.py in my project, But I can't import it in `admin.py` and `urls.py`. I try to use `sys`, and use Pycharm to mark them as Sources Root, but it still can't import! It always Report an error like:

```
from typeidea.custom_site import custom_site
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typeidea.custom_site'
```

Why `typeidea.custom_site` can't import?

My project directory and my code are here:

admin.py

```
from ..typeidea.custom_site import custom_site
...
@admin.register(Category, site=custom_site)
```

urls.py

```
import typeidea.custom_site

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^super_admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', typeidea.custom_site.custom_site.urls),
]
```

Project:

typeidea

-blog

——admin.py
...

--comment
...

--config
...

--typeidea

——**init**.py

——urls.py
...

custom_site.py

Comment: Don't post pictures of code.  Cut-and-paste the code.  Your inner files do not have any idea what the outer layers look like.  You might be able to do `from ..typeidea.custom_site import custom_site` (note the double dots).

Comment: What do you mean by "I try to use sys"?  You COULD do what you want by adding the root path to `sys.path`.  Did you try that?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have try to use sys.path

Comment: @TimRoberts My file custom_site.py is in the parent directory, I can't use so.

Comment: @TimRoberts Please told me that how to use sys.path.I don't know if I am using it correctly.

Comment: You can say `sys.path.append( os.path.abspath( os.path.dirname( __file__ ) + "/.." ) )` to add the current file's parent to the path.  Make it `"/../.."` to add the current file's grandparent.

Comment: @TimRoberts I find that I can use `sys.path.append("..") ` to import too! Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, but REMEMBER that `sys.path.append("..")` appends the parent of the CURRENT directory.  If you run the script from somewhere else (`python ../../admin.py`), that won't match the script location.

Answer (score 0):

when you write:
**from X import y**
it imports the X module, and create reference to the y objects/methods. yours:

from **typeidea.custom_site** import custom_site

the typeidea.custom_site is not a module, so you cant import it.

the module that you want to use is custom_site, so just do:

import custom_site.

for more detailed explanation about it:
[`from ... import` vs `import .`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import)