# imports: `import ...` vs `from ... import ...` when using aliases

Tags: python, python-import

I was browsing the pytorch documentation and noticed a different way of expressing imports that I never encountered before:

```py
import torch.nn as nn
```

I would have usually written this as:

```py
from torch import nn
```

At a first glance both methods look to me like they achieve the same thing, am I correct?
Are there any differences between those methods?
If not is there a best-practice suggesting to use one over the other?

Comment: Practically they're the same. Under the hood, they're different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import torch.nn as nn
```

This is a bit confusing since both names end with `nn`, so with a bit different example-

```
import torch.nn as x
```

This is like "assigning" `torch.nn` in `x`.
I.e. `x.foo` is exactly as `torch.nn.foo`.

```
from torch import nn
```

Here `nn` is an abberviation form. `nn.foo` is the same as `torch.nn.foo`.

There is another way to import with named imports:

```
from torch import nn as x
```

Which will allow you to call `torch.nn` module by calling `x`.
Hope it's more clear now

Comment: Thanks, but i feel my question still lacks an answer... Can you confirm that `import torch.nn as x` is absolutely identical to `from torch import nn as x`? If so do you also feel like there is a preferred way to do so? I was a bit confused by the example as well but it is [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#define-a-convolutional-neural-network)

Comment: yes. you can print x in each case and see that it's referring to the same module