# different import syntaxes in python

Tags: python, import, module

Here are three similar import statements that I am trying in Spyder:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
```

This code works perfectly well.
When I try:

```
from sklearn import datasets.load_iris
```

This gives "Invalid Syntax" error.
When I try:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from datasets import load_iris
```

It says "No module named datasets" error.
When I try:

```
import sklearn.datasets
from datasets import load_iris
```

It gives the same error "No module named datasets".

Aren't all these statements same and equivalent?? Why only one of them works? Please clarity.

Comment: "Aren't all these statements same and equivalent??" - no. Maybe you misread something somewhere, or you made a bad assumption, or you had a bad source.

Comment: I know I have misunderstood, would you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more elaborated answer to your question: [`from ... import` vs `import .`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import)

### TL;DR

Python expects a module, or package path, when using `import ...`.

For `from ... import ...` statements, the `from ...` part, works the same way as `import ...`, and expects a package or module path. The `... import ...` section allows you to import any **object** found within the submodule you've specified at `from ...`. It does not allow, however, to access specific namespaces from a given object (e.g.: `datasets.load_iris`)

Here is all the ways you import the function `load_iris` from your examples:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
load_iris()

# OR

import sklearn.datasets

# Create a namespace for sklearn.datasets.load_iris
load_iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris
load_iris()

# OR

import sklearn.datasets

# Use it directly
sklearn.datasets.load_iris()

# OR

import sklearn.datasets as datasets

# Create a namespace for sklearn.datasets.load_iris
load_iris = datasets.load_iris
load_iris()

# OR

import sklearn.datasets as datasets

# Use it directly
datasets.load_iris()
```

Regarding your last example:

```py
import sklearn.datasets
from datasets import load_iris


# CORRECT USE

import sklearn.datasets
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
```

You have imported `sklearn.datasets`, AS `sklearn.datasets`. To access the `datasets` module you imported, you need to specify the name you used during `import`.