# "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt" vs "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"

Tags: python, python-import

I want to know the difference between these two declarations:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Specifically the word `from`.
Can anyone help me to understand it?

Comment: The result is exactly the same. You can read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html. These will create a reference to the same module accessible with the name 'plt'.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import for various description of the syntactic difference.